# select region from sequence with Phobius output in Python

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I need to use a certain program, to validate some of my results. I am relatively new in Python. The output is so different for each entry, see a snippit below:

```
SEQENCE ID                              TM SP PREDICTION
YOL154W_Q12512_Saccharomyces_cerevisiae  0  Y n8-15c20/21o
YDR481C_P11491_Saccharomyces_cerevisiae  1  0 i34-53o
YAL007C_P39704_Saccharomyces_cerevisiae  1  Y n5-20c25/26o181-207i
YAR028W_P39548_Saccharomyces_cerevisiae  2  0 i51-69o75-97i
YBL040C_P18414_Saccharomyces_cerevisiae  7  0 o6-26i38-56o62-80i101-119o125-143i155-174o186-206i
YBR106W_P38264_Saccharomyces_cerevisiae  1  0 o28-47i
YBR287W_P38355_Saccharomyces_cerevisiae  8  0 o12-32i44-63o69-90i258-275o295-315i327-351o363-385i397-421o
```

So, I need the last transmembrane region, in this case its always the last numbers between o and i or vise versa. if TM = 0, there is no transmembrane region, so I want the numbers if TM > 0
output I need:

```
34-53
181-207
75-97
186-206
28-47
397-421
```

preferably in seperate values, like:

```
first_number = 34
second_number = 53
```

Because I will be using a loop the values will be overwritten anyway. To summarize: I need the last region between the o and i or vise versa, with very variable strings (both in length and composition).
Trouble: If I just search (for example with regular expression) for the last region between o and i, I will sometimes pick the wrong region.

Comment: Are these input data stored in a file?

Comment: sorry for late comment, but yes, It can either be outputted like this in the linux terminal, or stored in a file, that looks like the snippit above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the Phobius output is stored in a file, change 'Phobius_output' to the path, then the following code should give the expected result:

```py
with open('Phobius_output') as file:
    for line in file.readlines()[1:]:
        if int(line.split()[1]) > 0:
            prediction = line.split()[3]
            i_idx, o_idx = prediction.rfind('i'), prediction.rfind('o')
            last_region = prediction[i_idx + 1:o_idx] if i_idx < o_idx else prediction[o_idx + 1:i_idx]
            first_number, second_number = map(int, last_region.split('-'))
            print(last_region)
```